# Split comma- and pound-separated strings into different columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe , a column of which contains colon and pound-separated strings.

```
data$col1
                                                              col1
1:  3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1] 
2:   3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] 
3:   4#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0] 
4:       2#Tier_IV_benign EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] 
5:   3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] 
6:   5#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

I want to extract the elements of the string and split it into different columns.

```
                                                            col1   col2                col3    EVS1 ... EVS12   
  3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1]      3  Tier_III_Uncertain    1           1
   3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]      3  Tier_III_Uncertain    0           0
   4#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0]      4  Tier_III_Uncertain    0           0
       2#Tier_IV_benign EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]      2      Tier_IV_benign    0           0
   3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]      3  Tier_III_Uncertain    0           0
   5#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]      5  Tier_III_Uncertain    0           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read.table(text=gsub("[^A-Za-z_0-9-]", " ", data$col1), 
           col.names = c(paste0('col', 2:4), paste0('EVS', 1:12)))[-3]

  col2               col3 EVS1 EVS2 EVS3 EVS4 EVS5 EVS6 EVS7 EVS8 EVS9 EVS10 EVS11 EVS12
1    3 Tier_III_Uncertain    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    -1     1     1
2    3 Tier_III_Uncertain    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     1     1     0
3    4 Tier_III_Uncertain    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    2     0     1     0
4    2     Tier_IV_benign    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0
5    3 Tier_III_Uncertain    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1     0     1     0
6    5 Tier_III_Uncertain    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming DT shown reproducibly in the Note at the end replace non-word characters and also EVS= with space.  Then read that using fread and set the names.  Finally cbind DT to it.

```
DT2 <- fread(text = gsub("EVS=|\\W", " ", DT$col1))
names(DT2) <- c("col2", "col3", paste0("EVS", 1:(ncol(DT2)-2)))
cbind(DT, DT2)
```

### Note

```
library(data.table)

L <-   "3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1] 
   3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] 
   4#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0] 
       2#Tier_IV_benign EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] 
   3#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] 
   5#Tier_III_Uncertain EVS=[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]"

DT <- data.table(col1 = trimws(readLines(textConnection(L))))
```